# Unable to add Windows Target Version as Windows 10 in Visual Studio 2015 Cordova Project

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-10, visual-studio-cordova

In Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise edition when we select cordova project, Win10 option from Windows Target Version is missing. When we try to add the functionality to the existing project using below command:

```
cordova platform add windows@https://aka.ms/cordova-win10
```

It is not leaving any impact on the selected project, I suspect this line of message is suspicious for me:

```
NO UAP SDK exists on this machine.
```

From the error, I understand the system is missing Universal App Platform SDK but not sure what to do. I have checked all the visual studio tools have been installed. However, I just done repair on Visual Studio that took 4 hrs and ate plenty of my Internet but not successful.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have selected `Universal Windows App Development Tools` in the VS installer. You may need to go to modify to manually add it.

[image]

Comment: I just did select all in custom installation. I just removed VS and reinstalled from scratch and now it is showing Windows 10.0 option to me.

Comment: Actually VS2015 was installed in Windows 8.1 which I have just upgraded. May be this was causing the problem.

Comment: Definitely would be - you can't build Win 10 apps on Win 8.1

Answer (score 0):

On my side I had to specify the right Cordova CLI. After that the 10.0 option appeared.

```
Config.xml(double click) => Platforms => Check globally installed Cordova version
```